# Google script incorrect date conversion from string?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**The following code in my Google script:**

```
var checkin_date = new Date(customer.checkin); //customer.checkin format DD/MM/YYYY
Logger.log("%s", customer.checkin);
Logger.log("%s", checkin_date);
```

**Gives me:**

```
[18-10-28 23:28:06:662 PDT] 26/10/2018
[18-10-28 23:28:06:662 PDT] Mon Feb 10 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2020
```

Which is wrong, why?

Comment: The date is in string format so you can split the string by '/' and create a date with new Date again by passing dd,mm,yyy.

Comment: I am confused can you show a little example pls.

Comment: There are specific date string formats Date recognizes see https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp.  Or as noted above split it into 3 numbers and pass to Date(yy,mm-1,dd)

Answer (score 1):

```
var customer="26/10/2018"
var dateArray=customer.split('/'); //[26,10,2018]

//new Date(year, month-1, day)
var checkin_date=new Date(dateArray[2],dateArray[1]-1,dateArray[0]);
checkin_date=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(checkin_date), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),         "dd/MM/yyyy");
Logger.log(checkin_date)
```

Hope this could help

Comment: But `Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(checkin_date), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MMM").toUpperCase());` still gives me FEB :(

Comment: var checkin_date=new Date(dateArray[2],dateArray[1]-1,dateArray[0]);
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(checkin_date), Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MMM").toUpperCase());

Try now.

You were adding utilities.format to a date second time